# Shift rows with missing NaN's to it's own column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing a lot of netstat data and the way I have been handling my solution now is by just removing the row and referencing manually. If I see proto is NaN, I just parse the row completely. But I am unable to append the row and the rest of the dataframe due to mismatched sizing.

I was wondering if it would be possible to just take the row with empty columns and just move it to the preceding row appending it to a column.

E.g - This is what my dataframe looks like as of now

| Proto | LocalAddress | ForeignAdress | State | PID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | [0.0.0.0:7] | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4112 |
| [tcpsvcs.exe] |  |  |  |  |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0:111 | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4 |
| Can not obtain ownership information |  |  |  |  |

Which will hopefully turn into

E.g

| Proto | LocalAddress | ForeignAdress | State | PID | Process_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | [0.0.0.0:7] | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4112 | tcpsvcs.exe |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0:111 | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4 | Can not obtain ownership information |

Basically create a new column for the process names and keep appending to the prior line.

Comment: Is this a dataframe you are parsing, or some kind of text file?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am parsing a dataframe. The text file doesn't look anything that different otherwise. I'll also update the post with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start by adding the column `"Process_name"` and use [**`pandas.DataFrame.shift`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the value of the next row/cell of `"Proto"`. After that, drop the rows that not equal to `"TCP"` (or any condition you want) by using [**`pandas.DataFrame.drop`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Considering that your initial dataframe is named `df`, try this :

```
df = (df.assign(Process_name=df['Proto'].shift(-1))
      .drop(df[df['Proto'].ne('TCP')].index)
      .reset_index(drop=True)
     )
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

Comment: I am also getting the same errors as yours as well. I'm not sure as to why but I keep getting a "CancelledError: lambda-4ed5dd3cd4cff63cecf60a62530e5c7b". Which I have no idea what it is when googling the error.

Comment: If you're using Jupyter, restart your python kernel by clicking on the circle arrow and see if you still get the error. If the error persits, it might be an index lose issue.

Comment: Could this also be modified to check for multiple arguments as well? Like check for TCP and UDP?

Comment: Yes, in this case, you have to change the boolean mask from this `df['Proto'].ne('TCP')` to this `~df['Proto'].isin(['TCP', 'UDP'])`.

Comment: Awesome! Got this. `clean_CSV = (df.assign(Process_name=df['Proto'].shift(-1))
      .drop(df[~read_file_csv['Proto'].isin(['TCP', 'UDP'])].index)
      .reset_index(drop=True)
     )`

Comment: One last question, what about substrings? Like maybe only looking for 'CP' of TCP?

Comment: No worries. You can use in this case, `~df['Proto'].str.contains('CP')` as a boolean mask.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You said it is always in the next row, so we just need to get a Series of `Proto` which only contains the values of the rows with `NaN`. Then we just shift it by 1 and create a new column with it.

```py
cols = ['LocalAddress', 'ForeignAdress', 'State', 'PID']
df['process_name'] = df[df[cols].isna().all(axis=1)]['Proto'].reindex_like(df).shift(-1)
df = df.dropna(subset=cols)
```

Output:

```
  Proto LocalAddress ForeignAdress      State     PID                          process_name
0   TCP  [0.0.0.0:7]     0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING  4112.0                         [tcpsvcs.exe]
2   TCP  0.0.0.0:111     0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING     4.0  Can not obtain ownership information
```

Comment: I'm not sure as to why but I keep getting a "CancelledError: lambda-4ed5dd3cd4cff63cecf60a62530e5c7b". Which I have no idea what it is when googling the error.

Comment: oh that's weird, never heard of that. google says something with `asyncio`. maybe restart your system? is it maybe code before that new part which fails?

Comment: The restart took me a little bit farther but ended up with "Sample larger than population or is negative." Could this be a bad data issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know just from that error message. Without seeing the data and the whole code I guess I can't help here.